# Detect param type xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

detect if `<xsl:with-param>` calls with `select` attribute or using text node of the `<xsl:with-param>`. In other words how to detect parameter type if it is string or xpath notation of node?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "xpath notation of node". Is that the same as 'with `select` attribute' (which is an XPath expression that might evaluate to a string, or to a node)? I guess my main question is, are you asking how to detect the type of the parameter passed, or the syntax with which it was passed? (two different questions)

Comment: My primary objective to detect the parameter data type is node or string. I have not find any way to detect parameter type. So i wanted to detect if it is possible to know a parameter is passed via `select` or its text node value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reliable way in XSLT 1.0 of determining what type of argument has been passed. You need to design the interface differently so as to remove this requirement, e.g. by passing an extra parameter.

Comment: I think that would be my last resort.

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2.0 you can use the `instance of` operator:

```
<xsl:if test="$p instance of xsd:string">
```